# Rounding off happens even though I declared my variables as float in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, division

I have to count pos,neg and 0 vals and divide them by array size and return the three values with 6 decimal places.
Here is the array
6 -4 3 -9 0 4 1

i tried converting the variables to float and at every stage i used the float function

```
def plusMinus(arr):
    a=float(0.000000);
    b=float(0.000000);
    c=float(0.000000);
    for i in arr:
        if i==0:
            a=a+float(1.000000);
        elif i<0:
            b=b+float(1.000000);
        else:
            c=c+float(1.000000);
    a=a/(float(len(arr))-float(1));
    b=b/(float(len(arr))-float(1));
    c=c/(float(len(arr))-float(1));
    print ("{0:.6f}".format(c));
    print ("{0:.6f}".format(b));
    print ("{0:.6f}".format(a));
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())

    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    plusMinus(arr)
```

expected output:-
0.500000
0.333333
0.166667

my output:-
0.600000
0.400000
0.200000

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to declare your values as floats, just allow python do handle the values:

```
def plusMinus(arr):
    pos = 0
    neg = 0
    zer = 0

    for n in arr:
        if n > 0:
            pos += 1
        elif n < 0:
            neg += 1
        else:
            zer += 1

    print(format(pos / len(arr), '.6f'))
    print(format(neg / len(arr), '.6f'))
    print(format(zer / len(arr), '.6f'))
```